# How to embed metadata (i.e. JSON/XML) into an image file?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, metadata, barcode

In .NET suppose I have an application that can create and open an image that has its metadata defined in a seperate file (i.e. '.json'/'.xml'). It would spit or open the metadata file of the same name as the image file.

Now to make distribution of the image + metadata files easier, I want to eliminate the extra metadata file so that users can open an image and has all the relevent info about the image. What are some of the good strategies for embedding the data into the image file itself?

Here are a few possibilities I found by googling:

- Visual embedding:

  - Data encoded as 2D Barcode such as [QR Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code), [Data Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix) or [PDF417](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417).
  - Data drawn as plain text on the image, retrieved through OCR
- Format embedding:

  - Data inserted as [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg#Syntax_and_structure) comments/EXIF comments
  - Data inserted as [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Ancillary_chunks) text chunks

The basic requirements are:

- Data can be in JSON, XML or binary format, as long as it's machine-readable.
- Data can be in the KB's, up to several dozens of KB's. The more the better.
- For visual embedding:

  - Data should hold up well against a certain degree of lossy compressions.
  - The shape of the data 'zone' on the image's canvas should be as flexible as possible to better use the image's real estate.
- Support all common image formats. (bmp, jpg, png, gif, etc.)
- If possible, use open source .NET libraries.

Any advice welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: is it a client(or some kind of shareware) or server app? why not just use a database?

Comment: anyway I hope you won't end up with rarjpegs ))

Comment: @Boris: It's a client app. The idea is to display the metadata-embedded images on a website, and people can download the images and use the program to open them. Hey what's rarjpeg?

Comment: image decoders usually read files from the beginning and ignore the stuff that was written in the end of the file while many archivers skip the beginning of the file(which can be a SFX archive) and only start processing after they find the archive signature - so if you concat a jpeg with a rar file you'll get something you can view as jpeg and something that you can unpack. I suppose most forums will not allow you to attach such hacked jpegs ) so it was a joke of course you should not try to use this technique

Comment: Ah I see. I remember the days we used this technique to distribute questionable stuff :) Haven't thought about the forum attachment policy yet. Otherwise it will be a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to store the information as a string of XML in the EXIF portion of the .jpg file, maybe in the UserComment field (9286H) of the EXIF IFD.

Here is some info on [loading and saving metadata using gdi+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, how much data in bytes can the UserComment field hold?

Comment: "Unlimited", or 65535 bytes, according to the Exif spec.

Comment: Good enough for me! Also, would XMP work? It sounds like it's cross-format.